# Standard Salesforce Lead Convert into Contact

Tags: community

If my company uses standard salesforce to convert leads into contacts, can I track who converted the lead into contact?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

To avoid customization (fields, workflow, etc.), you can simply look at the **LastModifiedById** field for your converted Leads.   Once a Lead is converted, it becomes read-only and the Lead.isConverted field value is set to TRUE (which modifies the record).

So, the last person to modify the converted Lead will always be the one who physically converted it.  The Lead.OwnerId can be different.